# Interpreting cross-partial derivatives

Tags: industrial-organisation

Consider a duopoly setting. Firm $1$ has the following profit equation:
$\pi_1(q_1,q_2,v_1)=(a+v_1-q_1-\gamma q_2)q_1 .$
Where $a>0$ is a utility parameter, $q_i\geq0$ is the quantity and $v_i\geq0$ is the quality the of firm $i\in1,2$, and $\gamma\in(1,0)$ is the degree of product differentiation.(assume no cost - irrelevant).

Now, I first want to find the change in $\pi_1$ when firm $2$ increases its quantity. Then I calculate
$\frac{\partial\pi_1}{\partial q_2}=-\gamma q_1<0$.
Obviously, this means that $\pi_1$ decreases when $q_2$ increases.

Arriving to my question:

I want to find the change in $\frac{\partial\pi_1}{\partial q_2}$ when $\gamma$ increases. So I take the cross-partial derivative,
$\frac{\partial^2\pi_1}{\partial q_2\partial\gamma}=-q_1<0$.

How do I interpret this result?
Does this mean that "lower differentiation (higher $\gamma$) weakens the effect of a larger quantity of firm 2 (higher $q_2$) on the profits of firm 1 ($\pi_1$)?"

This makes no sense to me because just by looking at the profit equation above I can see that higher $\gamma$ means a stronger effect of $q_2$ on $\pi_1$.

P.S.
Is there a problem with taking the partial derivative w.r.t $\gamma$ when $\gamma$ is in an open set?

Thank you.

Comment: That has to do with the meaning of "large." Higher $\gamma$ does indeed mean that the effect is stronger. But since the effect on profits is clearly negative, a stronger effect must be more negative. So the absolute value of the effec gets larger, but the effect becomes smaller as it becomes more negative. An taking derivatives is usually a problem on domains that are not open.

Comment: It is actually more commun to inteprete $\partial^2\pi_1/\partial q_2\partial q_1$ whose sign defines whether the goods are startegic substitutes or complements.